# yas-choose-value files in dir

Tags: elisp, yasnippet

I'm trying to do a snipped with default values being files in a directory, but fail. Seems calling elisp-code in yas-choose-value need special treatment?

I know you can hardcode it. something like

```
${1:file-name$(yas-choose-value '("foo" "bar"))}
```

But I want to call 'directory-files' which should return the list ("foo" "bar"). So, something like:

```
${1:file-name$(yas-choose-value `(directory-files ~/some/path)`}
```

But I get all kinds of errors doing that. Most often:

```
[yas] elisp error! Symbol's value as variable is void: YY(foo bar)...
```

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the elisp syntax for the substitution, not the shell one. Also, you were missing a closing paren.

```
${1:file-name$(yas-choose-value (directory-files ~/some/path))}
```